# How to read, update and delete the existing XML file using node attribute value in Java

Tags: java, xml, regex, xslt, xpath

I am trying to read/update/delete the XML file on the basis of value found.

I have a XML with name `123456.xm`l with below format.

```
<ps>
  <p n="359" u="/ae/arabic/plan_book/plan_and_book.aspx"/>
  <p n="277" u="/ae/english/plan_book/plan_and_book.aspx"/>
  <p n="410" u="/ao/english/plan_book/plan_and_book.aspx"/>
</ps>
```

Now my new method in java will get Filepath (`c://java/Files/12345.xml`), n(277 - the value which will be checked in file) and U ("/de/english/plan_book/plan_and_book.aspx").

Logic for my java method will as below, but really don't know how to write.

**Adding/Appending Method Logic:**

1. Open the file `c://java/Files/12345.xml`
2. Search for all nodes and find the basis of value of n(277). There will be only one record for 277
3. If this value exists in the file then no updates are required else add the new node in  xml file, so for example if the value of n would have been (777), as this attribute record does not exists in file then it would have added a new record in file (`<p n="777" u="/ao/english/plan_book/plan_and_book.aspx"/>`).
4. Save the updated XML on same location.

**Deleting Method Logic:**

1. Open the file `c://java/Files/12345.xml`
2. Search for all nodes and find on the basis of value of n(277). There will be only one record for 277.
3. If this value exists in node attribute "n" then it will delete that node from the xml, else no update required.
4. Save the updated XML on same location.

Would appreciate if you share some good example or links for above implementaion.

Thanks.

Comment: you have got all the methods there. you only need to understand java xml apis. so google the following, "java read xml", "java write xml", "java xpath query", "java get xml attribute", "java remove xml node", "java file delete".

Comment: Yeah, but any code sample to start, do I need to use xpath or using regular expression will work for me..please suggest

Comment: Well, for me there are two ways to read XML file. first is to use XOM http://www.xom.nu/ and second is to use Java standard XML library. I suggest that you use XOM. It is easier but you require XOM library to be added into your project. Once and XML is read as DOM, you can manipulate it by XPath or just basic get child and attribute methods. Then finally remove node and save DOM to file. All examples is on XOM website.

Comment: xpath, don't use regex with xml.

Comment: @gigadot any good link to start, as in google it returns with some mix type of result

Comment: I don't use standard Java API but for XOM all good examples are on their website.

Comment: This kind of processing is usually easier to express in XSLT than in an imperative language -- either use my XSLT solution directly, or as an example of an algorithm for the solution of this problem. +1 for the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**This kind of processing is usually easier and simpler (no regEx required) to specify in XSLT than in an imperative language**.

The XSLT transformation below can be used directly, or it can give an idea how to implement the same algorithm in another language:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:param name="pAction" select="'delete'"/>
 <xsl:param name="pN" select="277"/>
 <xsl:param name="pU" select="'/de/english/plan_book/plan_and_book.aspx'"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*" name="identity">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
     </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="ps">
  <ps>
    <xsl:apply-templates select=
     "*[not($pAction = 'delete')]
     |
      *[$pAction = 'delete' and not(@n = $pN)]
     "/>
    <xsl:if test="$pAction = 'add' and not(p[@n = $pN])">
      <p n="{$pN}" u="{$pU}"/>
    </xsl:if>
  </ps>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="p">
  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="not(@n = $pN)">
      <xsl:call-template name="identity"/>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
      <xsl:if test="not($pAction = 'delete')">
          <xsl:call-template name="identity"/>
      </xsl:if>
     </xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the provided XML document:**

```
<ps>
    <p n="359" u="/ae/arabic/plan_book/plan_and_book.aspx"/>
    <p n="277" u="/ae/english/plan_book/plan_and_book.aspx"/>
    <p n="410" u="/ao/english/plan_book/plan_and_book.aspx"/>
</ps>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced:**

```
<ps>
   <p n="359" u="/ae/arabic/plan_book/plan_and_book.aspx"/>
   <p n="410" u="/ao/english/plan_book/plan_and_book.aspx"/>
</ps>
```

**when the parameter `$pAction`  is changed to**:

```
 <xsl:param name="pAction" select="''add'"/>
```

**then the result of the transformation is the same XML document (unchanged).**

**When the parameter is**:

```
 <xsl:param name="pAction" select="''add'"/>
```

**and the XML document is**:

```
<ps>
    <p n="359" u="/ae/arabic/plan_book/plan_and_book.aspx"/>
    <p n="410" u="/ao/english/plan_book/plan_and_book.aspx"/>
</ps>
```

**then the result is**:

```
<ps>
   <p n="359" u="/ae/arabic/plan_book/plan_and_book.aspx"/>
   <p n="410" u="/ao/english/plan_book/plan_and_book.aspx"/>
   <p n="277" u="/de/english/plan_book/plan_and_book.aspx"/>
</ps>
```

Comment: can you please suggest how to use your xslt in my java code and what it will do...thanks

Comment: Its out of mind, how should I use above xslt in my java code...please suggest guys and make sure it saves xml back to same location also

Comment: @M.S: The invocation of a transformation in Java or another PL is implementation-specific. You must decide what XSLT processor you want to use, then read its documentation for examples of invoking a transformation. Pay special attention how to pass parameters to the transformation: all three parameters can be specified dynamically by the invoker of the transformation. Finally, almost all XSLT processors can be invoked using a command-line utility -- thus one can avoid completely the need to write any Java or other PL code. See for example: http://saxon.sourceforge.net/saxon6.5.5/using-xsl.html

Comment: Actually  Dimitre Novatchev, above functionality is dynamic and will need some code to pass the parameters, I really don't have clue to use your xslt in my code and link provided is also not showing any help...please guide me

Comment: @M.S: As I already pointed out, passing parameters to a transformation is implementation -specific. Read the documentation of the XSLT processor you have decided to use. For example, if you use Saxon 6.5.5, you can find examples of doing this in a "samples" directory. I typically use an XSLT processor from the command line, or I use the .NET XslCompiledTransform from C# and can point you to the relevant MSDN documentation for passing parameters to the transformation -- but it seems you aren't into C#.

Comment: Yes this implementation needs to be done in java and implementing XSLT in java is not very clear...did anybody point to some good document

Comment: @M.S: This is why I referred you to read the appropriate documentation. *I* pointed you to a good document -- the samples directory of Saxon. All the necessary Saxon 6.5.5 documentation, including the complete Java API and samples can be reached from here: http://saxon.sourceforge.net/saxon6.5.5/

Answer (score 1):

***If and only if your XML is as simple as that sample you provided, you may use this:***

Following code would iterate over all matches of `<p>` elements:

```
try {
    Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("(?is)(<p n=\"(\\d+)\" u=\"([^\"<>]+?)\"/>)");
    Matcher regexMatcher = regex.matcher(subjectString);
    while (regexMatcher.find()) {
        // matched text: regexMatcher.group()
        // match start: regexMatcher.start()
        // match end: regexMatcher.end()
    } 
} catch (PatternSyntaxException ex) {
    // Syntax error in the regular expression
}
```

To find a specific node (better to say string) with a given number, use this syntax:

```
(?is)(<p n="#num_to_find#" )(u="[^"<>]+?"/>)
```

Where alter `#num_to_find#` with the number you choose. And then could replace like:

```
$1#string_to_replacewith##
```

**Regex Explanation**

```
"(?is)" +                       // Match the remainder of the regex with the options: case insensitive (i); dot matches newline (s)
"(" +                           // Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference number 1
   "<p\\ n=\"#num_to_find#\"\\ " +     // Match the characters “<p n="#num_to_find#" ” literally
")" +
"(" +                           // Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference number 2
   "u=\"" +                         // Match the characters “u="” literally
   "[^\"<>]" +                      // Match a single character NOT present in the list “"<>”
      "+?" +                          // Between one and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed (lazy)
   "\"/>" +                         // Match the characters “"/>” literally
")"
```

---

Hope this helps.

Comment: @Cylian..thanks, where to use above code as first I need to open the xml file and then do i need to use above code sample and also I am not able to understand this line (?is)(<p n="#num_to_find#" )(u="[^"<>]+?"/>) as well what value do I need to pass for subjectString Matcher regexMatcher = regex.matcher(subjectString);

Comment: This is the pattern for matching the ``p`` elements in general. But use ``(?is)(<p n="#num_to_find#" )(u="[^"<>]+?"/>)`` to find ``<p>`` elements with given number. Just change ``#cum_to_find#`` to the number you want.

Comment: ``$SubjectString`` is nothing but the entire text of input xml.